# Terminar bucle FOR en archivo bat

Tags: cmd, .bat

tengo la siguiente duda.

tengo un pequeño script que realiza Multiplexeo de archivos MKV, el archivo funciona adecuadamente, sin embargo tengo un pequeño problema.

Se tiene la siguiente instrucción:

```
FOR /F "delims=*" %%A IN ('dir /b *.MKV') DO "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" ^
--ui-language es --priority lower --output ^
```

Cuya instrucción:

```
FOR /F "delims=*" %%A IN ('dir /b *.MKV')
```

Hace que se haga el proceso a todos los archivos MKV que se tengan en ese lugar, pero el problema es que entra en bucle, como puedo hacer para especificar que solo debe hacer el proceso una vez?